# How jQuery handle cross domain requests errors?

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain

Considering that I don't have a callback method defined before and the following code:

```
jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'url',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {},
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            crossDomain: true,
            jsonpCallback: callback,
            async: true,
            success: function ( pData ) {
                //process success
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                //Log error
            }
});
```

The jQuery is handling the ajax Events ( success/error ) properly, with no error.
Why jQuery are doing that if in the API documentation is saying they can't do that?
And sometimes I get parserror, but I'm always returning the same content as JSON.

Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: Where does the documentation say it can't do that? jsonp is why it works....

Comment: you can't. jsonp requests do not trigger the error callback in recent versions of jQuery. I'm not entirely sure how previous versions handled it. This is the intended behavior. *"Note: This handler is not called for cross-domain script and cross-domain JSONP requests."* What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: I'm using jQuery v1.6.1. I know that it's a old version, but is a environment limitation.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type of error.

A parseerror may be catched(and will be catched )by jQuery when you use JSONP.(the documentation is not exact in this case)

But network-errors may not be catched, because JSONP does not make use of XMLHttpRequest, and therefore will not receive any status-codes that may indicate an error.